# Trouble using trig in top down game

Tags: java, trigonometry, angle

This is a pretty small issue but one that annoys me quite a bit.

Basically to give a bit of background I've made a small top down shooter and the player rotates towards the mouse. When they shoot the bullet goes on the angle it was shot at, but instead of originating at the player's coordinates, it comes from a gun.

This is working well but the only problem is, the cursor is set to be drawn where the mouse coordinates are. The bullet travels "underneath" the cursor instead of directly through it due to the offset like this: 
[image]

I want it to look like this: ->
[image]

I have spent about 2 hours trying to find a solution but the best I've come up with so far is

```
Player p = Client.pList.getPlayerByName(Client.username);
int cursX = (int) (p.getX() + Math.cos(mouseAngle) * Math.abs(mousePos[0] - p.getX()));
int cursY = (int) (p.getY() + Math.sin(mouseAngle) * Math.abs(mousePos[1] - p.getY()));
g.drawLine(cursX - 4, cursY, cursX + 4, cursY);
g.drawLine(cursX, cursY - 4, cursX, cursY + 4);
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Uh... don't use `mousePos`; use the gun's position?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are controlling the cursor drawing, then you could simply draw the cursor as the original mouse position (not from the player aim as you seem to be using) plus the offset of the gun from the center of the player — then it will appear on the bullet line. This requires no trigonometry other than the same calculation you used to determine the initial position of a fired bullet.

Another approach would be to aim the fire towards the actual mouse position. This is more complex, but I'll work it out if you're interested.